Неустойчиво вводные слова: теория и практика
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Термин "Неустойчиво вводные слова" был предложен в словаре: Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений: опыт словаря-справочника. М. : Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 501 с.
О какой группе  вводных слов идет речь и как выбрать правильное решение в этом случае?

ТЕОРИЯ
Теория вопроса рассмотрена в статье:
"Проблемы лексикографического представления вводных слов",  Кузнецова Наталья Владимировна, Почтарёва Ольга Викторовна, Тюменский государственный университет, Тюмень.
Чем интересна статья?

В ней дается список источников, которые обычно используются в этой теме (8 позиций).

Выделены четыре группы словарных единиц:


(1) всегда вводные (616 единиц, среди которых вероятно, итак, мол, напротив, судя по всему, страшно сказать, я бы сказал) – к ним мы применяем также термин «собственновводные слова»;
(2) всегда невводные (162 единицы, среди которых буквально, ведь, в какой-то мере, якобы, аналогично, как максимум, плюс ко всему, тем самым);
(3) вводные и невводные в определенных, четко разграничиваемых типах контекстов (103 единицы, среди которых безусловно, бесспорно, впрочем, однако, поистине, соответственно);
(4) «неустойчиво вводные», «как правило вводные», «вводные в случае
особого решения автора» и т.д. (228 единиц, среди которых авось, в
большинстве своем, в принципе, всё же, всё-таки, действительно, как
минимум, к тому же, наконец, небось, тем более).

Проведен подробный анализ решения для четырех единиц в группе неустойчивых вводных сочетаний: в принципе, небось, как  минимум, тем не менее.

Обозначены противоречивые решения в разных источниках, а также названы факторы, которые учитывались в них, например:


(1) Отнесение слова к разным группам из четырех указанных.
(2) Модальное значение: объективность или субъективность суждения определяет автор.
(3) Специализированные словари советуют автору прислушаться к себе и предоставляют полную свободу в выборе варианта пунктуационного оформления этой единицы; другие же такой свободы не предоставляют.
(4) Учитывается грамматика и структура, например вопросительный характер предложения; использование вводного слова как союзного средства, наличие уточняющего значения, инверсия.
(5) Учитывается интонационное выделение вводных слов (вот только интересно, как это делается).
(6) Даются примеры из литературы XIX века, но сейчас уже XXI век. Практика письма меняется.
Подобные формулировки предъявляют к пишущему 
высокие требования в плане развитости у него 
языкового чутья: нужно вникать в те смыслы, которые 
он хочет выразить, соотносить их с глубокими 
познаниями о грамматической системе русского языка 
и не бояться того, что информация в справочниках 
может расходиться с тем, что человек узнал в школе 
о русском языке. Пишущий должен провести целое 
«расследование», обратившись не только к 
специализированным и толковым словарям, но и 
проследив динамику в ответах экспертов портала 
«Грамота.ру» на вопросы пользователей.

После прочтения статьи возникает вопрос: нельзя ли по возможности обойти все эти факторы и предложить более простое решение для конкретной задачи. Вероятно, это можно связать с обычном анализом, когда учитываются три принципа пунктуации: семантика, грамматическая структура, интонация.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (список источников по теме)
 1. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический 
 справочник / под ред. В.В. Лопатина. М. : Эксмо, 2007. 480 с.
 2. Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по 
 правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию. 2-е изд., испр. 
 М. : ЧеРо, 1998. 400с. 
 3. Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь 
 вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений: опыт словаря-справочника. М. : 
 Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 501 с. 
 4. Пахомов В.М., Свинцов В.В., Филатова И.В. Трудные случаи русской 
 пунктуации. Словарь-справочник. М. : Эксмо, 2012. 576 с. 
 5. Большой толковый словарь русского языка / сост. и гл. ред. С.А. 
 Кузнецов. СПб. : Норинт, 1998. 1536 с. 
 6. Ожегов С.И., Шведова Н.Ю. Толковый словарь русского языка: 80 000 слов 
 и фразеологических выражений. 4-е изд., доп. М. : А ТЕМП, 2006. 944 с. 
 7. Словарь русского языка : в 4 т. / под ред. А.П. Евгеньевой. 2-е изд., 
 испр. и доп. М. : Русский язык, 1981–1984. 
 8. Словарь современного русского литературного языка : в 17 т. / под ред. 
 В.И. Чернышёва. М. ; Л. : Изд-во АН СССР, 1948–1965.
 


ПРАКТИКА
Вопрос: Местоименное наречие никак может быть вводным словом?

Проверяем источники

(1) В списках вводных слов у Лопатина и Розенталя этого слова нет. Нет его в справочнике: Пахомов В.М., Свинцов В.В., Филатова И.В. Трудные случаи русской пунктуации.
(2) Большой толковый словарь русского языка Кузнецова
 2. НИКАК, частица (в вопросит. предл.). Разг. 1. Употр. для 
 выражения неуверенности, предположительности высказывания; 
 кажется, как будто. Н. гроза? Н. он заболел? Н. кто-то 
 пришёл? 

Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.
 II част. разг.-сниж. 1. Употребляется при выражении 
 предположения, соответствуя по значению сл.: кажется, как 
 будто. 2. Употребляется как **вводное слово**, выражающее 
 предположение и соответствующее по значению сл.: *по- 
 видимому, кажется, как будто.*

Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений: опыт словаря-справочника. М. : Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 501 с. https://djvu.online/file/sCfaTLjOulHhW
 Неустойчиво вводное слово, решение об обособлении принимает 
 автор. Два значения: предположение с оттенком удивления (= 
 наверное), обособляется; вопросительная частица (= неужели, 
 разве), не обособляется.  Никак, заболела?  - Никак 
 заболела? 
 Приводятся примеры из классических текстов 19 века, и 
 делается вывод: есть тенденция чаще обособлять.


Итак, это неустойчиво вводное слово? Но вот в ПАС у Лопатина и в Справочнике Трудности пунктуации никак в качестве вводного слова не указано. В ответах Справочной службы его тоже нет.

А что там с практикой письма в Карте слов?  Практически никто не обособляет частицу никак, что соответствует словарю Кузнецова, то есть это частица с оттенком предположения, но не вводное слово. Поэтому тенденция однозначная ― обособления обычно нет.
 Ишь бледный какой ― никак заболели? 
 Никак заболел? Или соседство с людишками слишком плохо на 
 него влияет? 
 Да никак ты в бега собрался!
 Никак ты, собачья кровь со мной, королём, породниться 
 хочешь?– 
 Никак ты с неба свалился, гость наш знатный, забыл, что 
 здоровкаться надобно?


Так как же правильно?  Я могу предположить, что по семантике эту задачу однозначно решить сложно (не будет соответствия основным источникам), поэтому многое зависит от структуры предложения, от возможности интонационно выделить слово никак.

Ввиду малого объема частица никак легко вписывается в предложение, так что варианты с обособлением вводного слова встречаются не часто. В качестве вводного слова оно может использоваться в разговорном стиле, где его функция будет однозначно ясна.
И вот по стилю, по структуре предложения обособление никак  в примерах из классиков выглядит вполне обоснованным, например: Никак, даже темно в этой комнате.(Н.Гоголь). Но сейчас такая речь  кажется архаичной.

Решение задач

Никак заболЕла?  Это частица, так как сделать паузу после никак практически невозможно.  Сравнить: МОжет, заболЕла?  А в этом предложении пауза возможна, причем разница лишь в фонетике, а именно ударение на первом или втором слоге.
Также: Да ты никак обИделся? Да ты никак умирАть собрался?
Но вот учебный ресурс предлагает материал, где никак обособляется во многих случаях. Отметим сразу, что  подобные статьи источником служить не могут ― напротив, они должны давать ссылки на источники и приводить материалы из литературной практики с указанием на произведения. Однако, там другая практика))
Вот предложение: Никак, вы шпионите за мной. Из какого же произведения эта цитата? А вот из какого: — Вы никак шпионили за мной? — спросил Габриель, с подозрением глядя на Джулию. – Господа, вы никак шпионите за мной? ... Значит, я не ошибся – вы установили за мной слежку.
Соответственно, весь остальной материал не вызывает доверия.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений: опыт словаря-справочника.
НИКАК, частица; разг. Неустойчиво вводное, решение 
об обособлении принимает автор: никак обособляется 
в функции вводного в модальном значении 
«неуверенность, предположение» с оттенком удивления 
(= наверное); не обособляется в функции 
вопросительной частицы (= неужели, разве). Ср.: 
Никак, заболела? (К. Паустовский). - Никак 
заболела?
В функции вводного слова обособляется: А мне, никак
опять есть хочется (И. Тургенев); Никак, лет десять 
будет, как ты не бывал у нас? (Д.Мамин-Сибиряк); 
Никак, идет.(А.Островский); Никак, даже темно в 
этой комнате.(Н.Гоголь); Никак, я его еще помню? 
(М.Салтыков-Щедрин)> Никак, сама Рогатая мать- 
олениха оберегла вас, детей своих (Ч.Айтматов).
В функции вопросительной частицы не обособляется:
Никак ты пьян? (И.Горбунов); Никак ты плакать
собираешься? (А.Островский).
Есть тенденция частицу никак чаще обособлять.

